# Cartopy non-zero central longitude distorted with contourf

Tags: cartopy, contourf

I am trying to plot the surface temperature from a NetCDF file using Cartopy and contourf. The domain of my plot is 30S to 60N and 90.044495E to 89.95552E (so all the way around the Earth centered on 90W). Here is a section of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import wrf as wrf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
cart_proj = wrf.get_cartopy(skintemp)
lats, lons = wrf.latlon_coords(skintemp)
ax = plt.axes(projection=cart_proj)
ax.coastlines('50m', linewidth=0.8)
clevels = np.linspace(230,300,8)
cmap = plt.cm.YlOrRd
contours_fill = plt.contourf(wrf.to_np(lons), wrf.to_np(lats), skintemp, cmap=cmap, levels = clevels, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),extend="both")
cbar = plt.colorbar(contours_fill, shrink = .65, orientation='horizontal', pad=.05)
plt.show()
```

skintemp, lats and lons are all 2D arrays with dimensions (454, 1483), ordered (lat,lon), and cart_proj = wrf.projection.MercatorWithLatTS.

When I show the plot, it's distorted and incorrect:
[image: Full map with contourf]

I have determined that the issue has to do with the non-zero central longitude. The problem appears to be when the longitude changes from 179.90082 to -179.85632. lons.values[0,370]=179.90082, so I changed contourf to the following:

```
contours_fill = plt.contourf(wrf.to_np(lons[:,0:371]), wrf.to_np(lats[:,0:371]), skintemp[:,0:371], cmap=cmap, levels = clevels, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),extend="both")
```

which produces the following correct figure:

[image: West Part]

And when I change contourf to:

```
contours_fill = plt.contourf(wrf.to_np(lons[:,371:-1]), wrf.to_np(lats[:,371:-1]), skintemp[:,371:-1], cmap=cmap, levels = clevels, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),extend="both")
```

I get the other part of the map:
[image]

I cannot seem to get both parts of the map to display correctly together. I tried using contourf twice in the same plot, one for each section of the map, but only the last contourf line plots. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you try some other projections instead of Mercator?

Comment: I tried using LambertCylindrical(central_longitude=-90.0) and PlateCarree(central_longitude=-90.0) and both projections produce the same error.

Comment: I think there's a bug in CartoPy here. Can you open an issue at: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/new

Comment: I just opened an issue on GitHub. Thanks @DopplerShift